# Unity: What is Unity Measurements?

Tags: c#, coordinates, unity-game-engine, measure

What is Unity Coordinates Measurement? (cm, m, km)

How to Implement real measures in it?

I want to implement a real measures in Unity. how to do it?

```csharp
public Vector2 GetAsMeters (Vector2 vec) {
    Vector2 meters = new Vector2 (0, 0);
    while (vec.x > 1000) {
        vec.x -= 1000;
        meters.x++;
    }
    meters.x += vec.x;
    while (vec.y > 1000) {
        vec.y -= 1000;
        meters.y++;
    }
    meters.y += vec.y;
    return meters;
}
```

**EDIT**: How to implement a measurement like "Left 4 Dead"? (this game has a huge map and its as long as real kilometers)

Comment: There is no such thing, since you make everything as big or as small as you like. If you wish to make such mesurement you have to make a model or a sprite desired size and go from there. If you wish, 1 unit can be 1 meter or 1 cm or 1 km and so on.

Comment: Although in the case of physics, it is worth noting that by default the gravity setting treats 1 unit = 1 meter. If your world is scaled differently from this, you should change the gravity preset accordingly under Edit > Project Settings > Physics > Gravity, or the physical simulation may look off.

Comment: i want to know what does it mean "physics gravity on y is 2"? (i'm going to sleep so this might be late to see comments and answers thanks to all)

Comment: @HasanBayat likely means gravity in the y direction is twice as strong as normal. So that could mean that everything is twice as tall as it should be or that the map has special rules that make you fall twice as fast as normal.

Comment: Thanks @Scott Chamberlain. awesome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Unity, it's up to the developer to decide what a unit means. It's quite common that developers stick to 1 unit simply being 1 meter.

If you do that, you can calculate the length of a Vector2, in meters, by simply retrieving the magnitude of it.

```
float distanceInMeters = myVector2.magnitude
```

By sticking to 1 unit being 1 meter you can also measure the distance between two positions like this:

```
float distanceInMeters = Vector2.Distance(positionA, positionB)
```

Comment: This is true. when i need to create a city that street is 250km the its long in unity should be 250000.

Comment: @HasanBayat : You have to keep in mind that Unity (and every other 3D softwares) is not comfortable with very big worlds. You may see rendering artefacts when objects are too far. That's why youmay consider using 1 unity = 1km if you plan to have a city of 250km long.

Answer (score 3):

Unity measurement is by default in meters. If you want to change these units you just have to [make a converter class](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/140988/how-do-you-change-measurement-units-in-unity.html).

Make sure that you import in meters from Maya, 3Dmax or whatever 3D program you are working with because by default their measurements are in **cm**.

Answer (score 1):

If you want 1:1 pixel measurements don't forget to change your pixelperunit to 1 for your sprites so your in game vector measurements are more accurate to the sprites pixel size

Comment: It is a good idea. How can can i accept to answers at same time? ;)